# Crashing on app launch, "Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class"

Tags: android, xml

I am fairly new to android development and when im trying to inflate an xml, my application is crashing on launch with the following error. Any help is appreciated. thank you

Exception in the logs:

```
 01-16 17:13:34.033 1836-1836/com.example.android.inventoryapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.android.inventoryapp, PID: 1836
                                                                                android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                                    at com.example.android.inventoryapp.ItemCursorAdapter.newView(ItemCursorAdapter.java:29)
                                                                                    at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:285)
                                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2363)
                                                                                    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1970)
                                                                                    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:704)
                                                                                    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:765)
                                                                                    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1716)
                                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2162)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                                    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:433)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:726)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2346)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2068)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
01-16 17:13:34.034 1836-1836/com.example.android.inventoryapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 14 to dimension: type=0x4
                                                                                    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:720)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4205)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:579)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:211)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:207)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:203)
                                                                                        ... 58 more
```

my xml for a list item that is being used in a list view on another xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_margin">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#2B3D4D"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_item_margin"
        tools:text ="Sunglasses"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/list_item_margin" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#AEB6BD"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_item_margin"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:text ="7"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/list_item_margin" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sell_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_item_margin"
        tools:text="Sell"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/list_item_margin" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Dimens:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="activity_margin">16</dimen>
    <dimen name="list_item_margin">35dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Stackoverflow is asking me to add more details but there are not any, as far as i can see, so i am making up these lines to pass the error.

Comment: Look further on in the stack trace for the root Exception. The outer `InflateException` isn't going to tell you much.

Comment: Have you forgotten to add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` at the top of the xml file? Or just copied it without it?

Comment: @ReneFerrari copied without it :/ sorry.

Comment: @Mike M. I added the full exception in the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your `dimens.xml` file under the `values` folder? If not then this might cause the problem. If you have provided dimensions for certain API's but have not provided all of them under `values/dimens.xml` inflating should not work.

**EDIT:** `activity_main` needs `dp` appended meaning:     `<dimen name="activity_margin">16dp</dimen>`

Comment: Hi Rene, yes my dimens.xml is under values file

Comment: dang. Had a similar issue once so I thought it had to do with that. Could you please provide your dimens file (just add it in the question)? I don't wanna got to sleep until I solved this :D

Comment: Actually yes, the problem has something to do with the dimens file :/ when i delete all the paddings pointing to the dimens file, the crash is fixed. ill try to spot what the actual problem is. adding dimens to the post

Comment: added dimens to the original post

Comment: Well those are the things you get blind for sometimes ;)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add DP here:

```
<dimen name="activity_margin">16</dimen>
```

It should be:

```
<dimen name="activity_margin">16dp</dimen>
```